# get contents of multiple files using webapp2

Tags: python, multipartform-data, webapp2

I am uploading multiples files at the same time using

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

On the backend, I am using webapp2. I wish to access file contents of all the files uploaded. i am able to get the filenames using

```
def post(self):
        for file_data in self.request.POST.getall('fileToUpload'):
            self.response.out.write(file_data.filename)
```

However, I am not able to get the individual contents.
Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question after a few more searches :

```
for file_data in self.request.POST.getall('fileToUpload'):
     print "File Contents : ", file_data.value
```